# Решить задачу по SQL на Nowrthwind

Tags: sql

Вывести заказы со всеми позициями, указав для них наименования категории товара и имени товара.

Вроде вывел все правильно, но препод ругает ответ

> Вам нужно получить позиции заказа и добавить к ним информацию о
> наименовании категории и товара (в предложении "from" будет одна основная
> таблица и две доп. таблицы с левым соединением).

Как соединить все это в левое соединение в душе не чаю.

Ещё не особо понял что за позиция заказа и где ее брать.

```sql
select CategoryName as "НАИМЕНОВАНИЕ КАТЕГОРИИ",
       productname as "ИМЯ ТОВАРА"
from Orders, Categories, Products
```

Comment: Правильно ругается. Начать с того, что картезианское произведение уже давно почти что моветон...

Comment: почитайте про соединения: LEFT (левое) JOIN (соединение)

Comment: @Konst Так автор же и говорит о том, что не знает как левое соединение сделать :)

Comment: @Akina, а что там сейчас модно, CROSS JOIN?

Comment: @TigerTV.ru Если нужно картезианское - да, CROSS JOIN. А если есть условие связывания, то INNER JOIN. К тому же есть ещё одна тонкость - приоритет запятой ниже JOIN, так что `FROM A, B JOIN C ON A.x=C.x AND B.y=C.y` приведёт к ошибке Unknown column, в отличие от CROSS JOIN.

Comment: @Akina, Хмм... Работает [здесь](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_asc) `select * FROM [Orders] a, [Products] b
JOIN [OrderDetails] c
on c.OrderID=a.OrderID and c.ProductID=b.ProductID`. Ошибки нет.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru Особенности конкретной СУБД. Имеет право.

Comment: @Akina, а на какой СУБД появлялась ошибка?

Comment: @TigerTV.ru Наблюдается на: Firebird 3.0, MariaDB 10.1-10.6, MySQL 5.5-8.0, Oracle 11g, 18c, 21c, PostgreSQL 9.5-14, SQL Server 2014-2019. Скорее всего список версий ещё шире. Не наблюдается на: DB2, SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

итоговый ответ с левым соединением выглядит так

```sql
select * , ProductName as "Наименование продукта" ,categoryname as "категория продукта"  
from [Order Details] 
left join Products 
on [Order Details].ProductID = Products.ProductID 
left join Categories 
on Products.CategoryID = Categories.CategoryID
```